# Animated (or motion captured??) horror movie, Asian, where green fog (from the sea?) turns people into monsters

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I am trying to track down an animated (possibly motion captured) movie.
I watched it on a German streaming service, somewhere around 2010 to 2015, I think.
90% sure it was an Asian production.

The plot revolved around 2 women, and some kind of green fog drifted into the city, turning all humans into really really disturbing sea monsters (vaguely froglike with lots of limbs.)

One of the women turned into one of the monsters, the other eventually escaped onto a ship, leaving the city covered in green fog behind.

The whole movie was very very sickly green all the time.

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could this be ***[Gyo: Tokyo Fish Attack](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1857718/)*** (2012)...?

From IMDB:

> The friends Kaori, Erika and Aki are on a vacation to celebrate their upcoming graduation, when suddenly an infestation of mysterious walking fish forces them to reevaluate everything they care about in order to stay alive.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!